# How can we make a TextArea uneditable in GWT?

Tags: gwt

Is there any way for making TextArea uneditable in GWT?If yes please help me to sort out the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of GWT do you use? in 2.6 there is a setReadOnly(boolean readOnly) method.

Comment: Read more about [HTML <input> disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

Answer (score 4):

```
setReadOnly(true)
```

is translated into HTML as shown below

```
 <textarea class="gwt-TextArea gwt-TextArea-readonly" name="name" readonly=""></textarea>
```

This will work fine in HTML 4.01 and HTML5 but not in XHTML as defined at ***[HTML  readonly Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_readonly.asp)***

> In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the readonly attribute must be defined as

```
<textarea readonly="readonly">
```

Try this one to disable a text area field that will work in all the cases.

```
textArea.getElement().setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```

---

Same thing applies for

```
setEnabled(false)
```

that is translated into HTML as shown below

```
<textarea class="gwt-TextArea" name="name" disabled=""></textarea>
```

This will work fine in HTML 4.01 and HTML5 but not in XHTML as defined at ***[HTML  disabled Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)***

> In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the disabled attribute must be defined as

```
<input disabled="disabled" />
```

Try this one to disable a text area field that will work in all the cases.

```
textArea.getElement().setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setEnabled(false)
```

?

That seems to work nicely across browsers.

Comment: It's difficult to read the text when textarea is disabled due to disabled style.